# How to handle this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

How to deal with this integral ?
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\cdots\int_{a}^{b}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x_{1}\,\mathrm{d}x_{2}\cdots\mathrm{d}x_{n}}
{1 + x_{1}^{2} + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2} + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}x_{3}^{2} + \cdots + x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}\cdots x_{n}^{2}}
$$
where $b > a > 0$.

Is there a proper way to bring the denominator to numerator with some transformation and then do the integral ?.

Comment: can you recheck the denominator , i am not getting the pattern itself. moreover for how $n$ different variables we are integrating w.r.t why is there only one integral limit

Comment: The pattern in the denominator seems to be $1, x_1^2, x_1^2x_2^2, \ldots $, i.e. you mash the $x_i^2$-factors together one extra factor at a time and take a cumulative sum (is seems obvious to me at least). I'd assume the limits hold for all variables based on the way it's written out, but I'll admit some clarification would help.

Comment: @avz2611, corrected thanks

Comment: ah all right , i read the denominator completely wrong

Comment: If we neglect the fraction (constant) the integral is just $(b-a)^n$

Comment: @A.Sh, that's right

Comment: Is there any reason to expect a general (that is, valid for every $n$, $a$, $b$) closed formula? Or were you asked to show convergence only?

Comment: @Did, I wondered if there is a solution.